# Why does req.socket.address().address show a different IP address than my actual public IP address?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, ip-address

I am writing a small application in Node.js which requires me to obtain the IP address. I am doing this by using req.socket.address().address which gives me the output of home -> 127.0.0.1. My understanding is this is because its behind some kind of VPN.

However, in the AWS console that I'm using my public IP is a different value. My question is how can AWS determine my IP address and the Node.js req.socket.address().address method gives me the generic IP of localhost?

Comment: What compute service are you working with?

Comment: It's the public ip on my EC2 instance. I'm just playing around - the small web application isn't specific to EC2 / AWS. I just noticed whilst looking at these two different things.

Comment: The logical explanation would be that *you* are not the client on this socket, but rather an upstream proxy like Nginx is running on your instance, and connecting the request to Node.  Your IP address would likely be found in the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header, if that is the case, but there's not enough info in the question to determine this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [EC2 Instance Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) to get your public IP on an EC2 instance.

Metadata categories can be found from the following endpoint (call it from your EC2 instance):

> http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

Append a category to the end of the previously mentioned URL to get the metadata value.  In your case, I think this is what you are looking for:

> http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I'm wondering why the Node.js function shows a different IP address than the EC2 public ip address - I don't have a problem accessing the EC2 public ip address

Comment: Ah, I misread your question.  I thought you were asking two questions, and I was attempting to answer the first.  It wasn't clear to me that you were able to determine the public ip address from your code.